# c# multiple web.config files in a single project under different folders?

Tags: c#, web-config

Can we have multiple web.config files in a single project in c#?
if yes then what is its benefit?
Say I have a project ABC that has three folders under it.
Now ABC has its web.config file, so does each folder under ABC.
so there are total 4 web.config files.
So what will be the output when I run the project?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can have multiple web.config files in the separate folders.  They can be used to enable/disable modules on a per folder basis.  You can even set up each of those folders as separate web sites, even sub-sites, that use some modules from the parent web.config and some from the sub-site web.config.

I wrote up a blog post in the past about using BlogEngine.NET as the main site and configuring the web.config file in sub-sites.  It might be of some help to you:  http://markschlegel.com/post/2011/11/26/BlogEngineNET-a-sub-site!.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. An example of what this is used for is the default MVC 3 project template. There is one web.config for the site, and there is one inside the Views folder to deal with rendering the views.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The ASP.NET MVC project templates do this to restrict browsing the `Views` folder.